# How to modify multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript

I have this array

```
[[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34],[41],[43],[51]]
```

,

expected output like this: `11-14,21-24,31-34,41,43,51`

Comment: Do you just want to output as this format?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: If the length of the nested array is 1, return `array[0]`. Otherwise, concatenate the first and last elements with `-` between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it via `Array.map()`

```js
const data = [[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34],[41],[43],[51]]

let result = data.map(d => {
   if(d.length < 2){
     return d[0]
   }
   return d.at(0) +' -' + d.at(-1)
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
[[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34],[41],[43],[51]].map((arr) => {
  if(arr.length > 1){
     return `${arr[0]}-${arr[arr.length-1]}`
  }
  return `${arr[0]}`;
})
```

['11-14', '21-24', '31-34', '41', '43', '51']

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [[11,12,13,14],[21,22,23,24],[31,32,33,34],[41],[43],[51]]
const result = data.reduce(
  (a, arr) => [...a, arr.length >= 2 ? `${arr[0]}-${arr[arr.length - 1]}` : arr[0]], 
  []
)

console.log(result)
```